# Timezone issues when running my django app on Heroku

Tags: django, datetime, heroku, timezone, web-deployment

I'm creating a scheduling app with Django. As per most recommendations on the topic, the appointments (in my Appointments model) are stored in UTC timezone format. So my *settings.py* are set to `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`.The app was working perfectly on my local server, but when I deployed it to Heroku, i started having issues.

To give you an example (in production):

```
>>> heroku run bash
>>> python manage.py shell
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 17, 10, 10, 453536)
```

Yet, on local, I get:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 13, 10, 10, 196794)
```

I tried to solve the issue (ie, 4-hour difference) by changing the TZ config value of the app to my local time, like so:

`heroku config:add TZ='America/Toronto'`

No luck. Anyone understands why this is happening? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: `heroku config:add TZ="America/Toronto"`?

Comment: Is that incorrect? I'm using the TZ database names provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Choose your closest TZ with your city

Comment: Which is Toronto... I don't understand what your comment is about...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

or, based on documentation best practices:

```
datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)

datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 19, 33, 32, 335610)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 18, 33, 37, 582409)
>>>

>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 18, 32, 56, 146774, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: `timezone.now()` is the best practice, I'm using the same in all my apps. There is no issue with that until now.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get the same time with or without .utcnow()

Comment: @MaximVallee it works perfectly fine. Just look at my updated answer.

Comment: @ Sam I think you're misunderstanding my problem. The solution you suggested returns the Heroku server's time, which is not the same as my local time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Toronto')
print(datetime.now(tz))
```

This will print the current datetime as per your timezone (America/Toronto)